# Are indirect cyclic dependencies ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

I'm the middle of creating a RoR application which needs a *Many-to-many* association between the same table (at least in theory).

How so? Well, I'd need a *User* table which contains two kind of users: *Server*, and *client*, more or less like the idea of a Teacher and a student (with private lessons, but with multiple teachers), or a *Doctor* and a *Patient*

My first idea was to simply make a User table (you know, login, email, and personal info) and assign it a *Role* (Server, or client), but then I thought that making such association with a third-table would troublesome

USER <-----> USER_USER

But the idea of creating two "login" tables that represent each role, and a third-table for the association sounds wrong.

Client_Login <-----thru---> Client_Server <---thru---> Server

For simplicity sake, a client cannot be a server to another clients, and a server cannot be a client for another server.
Obviously, a server can have multiple clients, and a client has multiple servers

How would recommend modeling this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to explicitly have different methods between the two, Server and Client, which I am assuming since you want different classes. Then you might want to look into Single Table Inheritance(STI).  This will allow you to use one User table, but have two different models that use it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :another_model #example association that will exist for all user types
    self.inheritance_column = :role 
    # if you need to be able to tell what role are available
    def self.roles
      %w(Client Server)
    end

end

class Client < User
   has_many :server_clients
   has_many :servers, through: :server_clients
end 
class Server < User
   has_many :server_clients
   has_many :clients, through: :server_clients
end
```

You then have to just setup a simple server_client.rb model for the bridge.

example from here: http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

This will allow you to put common functionality for all Users in the User class, and specific functionality in the respective classes of Server and Client.

Answer (score 1):

It's done all the time.  It's quite common to have a many-to-many back to yourself.  It's common in hierarchies dealing with people's relations to each other, (dependency, managers, children, etc... )

```
class User
  has_many :user_relations, dependent: destroy, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :dependent_users, through: :user_relations

  has_many :dependent_upon_users, through: user_relations, source: 
:dependent_upon
end

class UserRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dependent_upon, class_name: User

  validates_presence_of :user, :dependent_upon
end
```